# retain original caller id on Call transfer on asterisk

Tags: asterisk, telephony, pbx, conference, sip-server

I am running a B2C outbound Campaign on **VicidialNow C.E 1.1** as **Asterisk Server** / **SIP Server**.

The call is made from server to customer and connected to agents waiting for calls. The agents transfers the call to third party (not a blind transfer). The 3rd party sees the Caller ID of agent.

Now, what I want is to display the caller id or the phone number of the customer to the 3rd party.

I Googled and searched over SO, found this ***sendrpid=pai*** to add on sip.conf file. but this functionality only supports on 1.4 or upgraded version.

**scenario:**

Agent calls the Customer's phone ex 12123344 and call is received. Agent puts Customer on hold and dials Mr XX, another phone number (not the extension of sip server) ex 21214433. The conference call is made(customer, agent and Mr. XX are in conference). I want Mr. XX to see the Customers Number asap the Customer is Connected to the conference.

Comment: Please show us the relevant Part of your dialplan (extensions.conf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture the incoming CID information into a channel variable when the call first comes in:

```
exten => foo,1,Set(ORIG_CID=${CALLERID(all)})
```

... then set the CID just before you dial to be the contents of the channel variable.

Comment: but here the customers are not making calls to us, we are calling them and transferring line to another phone number. I have edited the question, can you help any further..Thanks in advance

Comment: Ok, you're asking two different questions... one place you say "transfer", the other you say "conference call".  These are very different problems with very different solution sets.  Please clarify which it is you mean.

Comment: Sorry for any mistakes..i would like to go for conference call