# Asterisk Attended Transfer: How to Retain Caller ID

Tags: asterisk, sip

(I'm new to Asterisk.) Why is Asterisk showing `asterisk` on the phone when you do an attended transfer?

This is the Scenation:

- I've registered 2 SNOM 300 phones and a software Switchboard application to my asterisk server
- When I dial extension 1499 on phone 1, it rings on the switchboard
- I Answer the call, and transfer it to Phone 2. The switchboard is executing an attended transfer at this point (*2)
- On Asterisk the call is put into the queue but when phone 2 rings it only shows `asterisk` instead of the extension number of phone 1

This is what I've done to see what is happening:

When the call comes in it goes into the context and execute this

```
exten => _1499,1,Set(CALLERID(name)=${CALLERID(num)})
exten => _1499,n,NoOp(#################### ${CALLERID(num)} ${CALLERID(name)})
exten => _1499,n,Queue(swb_q,tTkK)
```

On asterisk it shows the CallerID as 1904 which is correct.

When the call is transferred it goes to the TRANSFER context and this code is executed

```
exten => _19XX,1,Gosub(ENDRECORD,s,1)
exten => _19XX,n,NoOp(#################### ${CALLERID(num)} ${CALLERID(name)})
exten => _19XX,n,Set(_TransToExt=${EXTEN})
exten => _19XX,n,NoOp(IN TRANSFER ${TransToExt})
exten => _19XX,n,Gosub(RECORDING,s,1)
exten => _19XX,n,Dial(Sip/${EXTEN},40,tT,kK)
```

but not the `CALLERID(num)` and `(name)` variables are blank. Now I'm sure it is because I'm on a different extension or channel or something.

How can I retain the Caller ID of the incoming call, and when the Switchboard transfer the call, pass that CID to Phone 2?

Any help will be appreciated. Google have a lot on transfers, but I'm struggling to find something close to this.

I've looked at this 
[retain original caller id on Call transfer on asterisk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167492/retain-original-caller-id-on-call-transfer-on-asterisk) 
but I'm not sure if it is helpful, because there is not a lot of detail in the Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer after a long search.

You can use Variable inheritance.
https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Variable+Inheritance

This allowed me to store the incoming CID into a variable I called `EXTERNAL_NUM` like this:

```
exten => _1499,n,Set(__EXTERNAL_NUM= ${CALLERID(num)})
exten => _1499,n,Queue(swb_q,tTkK)
```

Note the 2x`_` in from of the Variable Name. 2x`_` is used for Multi Inheritance. 1x`_` is used for single inheritance. See the link that I posted for an explanation.

In my Transfer context I use this variable without the `__` like this:

```
exten => _19XX,1,Gosub(ENDRECORD,s,1)
exten => _19XX,n,Set(_TransToExt=${EXTEN})
exten => _19XX,n,NoOp(IN TRANSFER ${TransToExt})
exten => _19XX,n,Gosub(RECORDING,s,1)
exten => _19XX,n,Set(CALLERID(num)=EXTERNAL_NUM)
exten => _19XX,n,Dial(Sip/${EXTEN},40,tT,kK)
```

Hope this helps somebody else that have the same type of problem, or just needs to use variables inheritance sometime.